# Setting up VScode for C++ and I get redirected to settings.json every time I try try to hit debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've already installed and set up all of the necessary technologies to make C++ run in VScode, including the C/C++ debugger extension, the C/C++ compiler extension, the coderunner extension, and minGW. I'm using Visual Studio Code version 1.51.1, C/C++ extension version 1.1.2, C/C++ compile and run extension version 1.0.13, and Code Runner version 0.11.1.

When I just run my code it runs in the terminal properly, and when I intentionally put bugs in the code the terminal reads out the proper error messages. The issue is when I try to run the debugger, I get redirected to settings.json and the debugger does nothing.

Just to be clear this question is about the VScode software itself, not the C++ program I wrote, which was just a simple hello world.

The json in settings.json looks like this:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\jjpot\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe",
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have slogged through [Using GCC with MinGW](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)?

Comment: It just sounds like you haven't configured everything. I'm not familiar with all of those extensions, so I unfortunately couldn't say what's left to configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have minGW and VS Code setup on my windows. You can try my setup and see if it solves your issue of debugging.

Inside your project folder make another folder .vscode and add these three files :

1. [tasks.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9f2V.png)
2. [launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQMJg.png)
3. [c_cpp_properties.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDW0M.png)

In `launch.json` edit "miDebuggerPath": "<your_path_to_debugger>\\gdb.exe"

In `c_cpp_properties.json` edit "compilerPath": "<Your_compiler_path>//bin"

[The project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvjvz.png) Should look something like this.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! I'm a newcomer to compiled languages and VScode in general so I didn't know that I had to edit those files to finish setup. Super helpful :)